# Is the OS always the server?

Tags: operating-system, client-server, message-passing

Given the server-client model, would the OS initiate messages to applications, or is message passing always initiated by programs that want to use resources and thus must communicate with the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS is an overloaded term, and application is a vague term.

A pure message passing OS might implement traditional (unix) system calls in applications.  For example, you might have an application called FileSystem, which accepts messages like Read,Write,Open,Close....  In these, such an application would be considered a *server*, and the *client* would be an application which wanted to use the File Services.

Pure message passing systems typically have difficulty with asynchronous events.  When you look at implementing a normal *read* system call in a message passing system, it is natural that it will be an RPC:  the client sends a read request, then suspends until the server has satisfied the read and sent a reply.

When the client wants asynchronous notification, such as send me a message when there is new mouse events available; the RPC somewhat falls down.   While purely asynchronous systems exist, they are cumbersome to use with plain old programming languages like C, C++, ...  There is hope that message based languages like Golang can break the impass, but that is yet to be seen.

Higher level OS-like services may deploy a number of interaction methods, quite distinct from client serve.  Publish-Subscribe, a more recent reimplmentation of the 1980s multi-catch, has been popular in the last decade.  Clients subscribe to a set of channels that they are interested in, and every event delivered to that channel is copied to every client subscribed to the channel before it is retired.  Normal clients can generate events as well, so the mechanism serves as a dynamic interconnect between modules.

Dbus + zeromq are P-S systems of differing scales.  Note that both can be implemented outside of a message passing OS.